# rails :dependent=>:destroy being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

My association option does not appear to be honored.

```
class ClassRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :class_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :people, :through=>:class_assignments

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :class_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :class_rooms, :through=>:class_assignments

class ClassAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :class_room
```

That is to say, when either a person, or a class room is deleted, the record in the join table/model should also be deleted.

However, `ClassRoom.last.destroy` destroys the `ClassRoom`, but no any of it's associated `ClassAssignments`.

I know `:dependent=>:destroy` is ignored when `:through` is used, but I should be able to use it on the join model right?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  class ClassRoom < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def before_destroy
    self.class_assignments.destroy_all
  end
```

same for person